# Как узнать возраст файла на ассемблере?

Tags: windows, ассемблер, дата, masm32, intel

Всех приветствую))

Задачка такова:
"Используйте функцию GetOpenFileName для выбора файла. Проверьте, если возраст файла меньше 3 дней, выполните его. В противном случае выведите диалоговое окно с вопросом об удалении файла. Если пользователь согласен, удалите."

Проблема:
Я никак не могу получить возраст файла. Я пытаюсь сравнить время создания, возвращаемое `GetFileTime`, с текущим временем, возвращаемым `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`. 3 дня - это (3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 10000000) 100-нс интервалы (в таких единицах измеряется FILETIME). Для упрощения своей задачи сравниваю только старшие части `dwHighDateTime` структур FILETIME, вес младшей части 429 секунд, меньше 10 минут.

Вот как-то так:

```
invoke GetFileTime, hFile, addr ftCreate, NULL, NULL
invoke GetSystemTimeAsFileTime, addr ftNow
mov eax, ftNow.dwHighDateTime
sub eax, ftCreate.dwHighDateTime8
cmp eax, ((3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 10000000) / 0x100000000)
jg l1
```

Но я получаю эти ошибки:

```
;для этого: mov eax, ftNow.dwHighDateTime
Third.asm(63): ошибка A2006: неопределенный символ: dwHighDateTime

;для этого: cmp eax, ((3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 10000000) / 0x100000000)
Third.asm(65): ошибка A2206: отсутствует оператор в выражении
```

Помогите пожалуйста с этой проблемой.

P.S. Если у кого-то есть другие идеи по решению этой проблемы (я имею в виду возраст файла), вы можете порекомендовать его))

.Inc файл

```
include WINDOWS.inc
 
include user32.inc
include kernel32.inc
include comdlg32.inc
 
includelib user32.lib
includelib kernel32.lib
includelib comdlg32.lib
 
.data
    Time_title  db ' Lab_3',0
    format db 'More than 3 days. Delete file?', 0
    buf db 255 dup(0)   
    hFile dd 0
    readed dd 0
    hmem dd 0
```

.Asm файл

```
.386
.model flat,STDCALL
option casemap :none  ;case sensitive
include Third.inc
include RADbg.inc
 
Mem_Alloc PROC Buf_Size:DWORD
    add Buf_Size,4  
    invoke GlobalAlloc,GMEM_MOVEABLE or GMEM_ZEROINIT,Buf_Size
    push eax 
    invoke GlobalLock,eax 
    pop [eax]
    add eax,4
    ret
Mem_Alloc endp
 
Mem_Free PROC DATA:DWORD
    mov eax,DATA
    sub eax,4   
    mov eax,[eax]   
    push eax        
    push eax
    call GlobalUnlock   
    call GlobalFree 
    ret
Mem_Free endp
 
.code
Begin:
    call main
    invoke ExitProcess,NULL
 
main proc
    LOCAL ftCreate, ftNow: FILETIME;
    ;LOCAL stUTC, stSysTime: SYSTEMTIME;
 
    invoke Mem_Alloc, 1000h
    mov hmem, eax
    invoke Mem_Alloc, sizeof OPENFILENAME
    mov edi, eax
    assume edi: ptr OPENFILENAME
    xor eax, eax
    mov [edi].lStructSize, sizeof OPENFILENAME
    mov [edi].lpstrFile, offset buf
    mov [edi].nMaxFile, 255
    invoke GetOpenFileName, edi
    invoke CreateFile, [edi].lpstrFile, GENERIC_READ,\
        FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,\
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL
    mov hFile,eax
    ;invoke GetFileTime, hFile, addr ftCreate, NULL, NULL
    ;invoke FileTimeToSystemTime, addr ftCreate, addr stSysTime
    ;invoke GetSystemTime, addr stUTC
 
    invoke GetFileTime, hFile, addr ftCreate, NULL, NULL
    invoke GetSystemTimeAsFileTime, addr ftNow
    mov eax, ftNow.dwHighDateTime
    sub eax, ftCreate.dwHighDateTime
    cmp eax, ((3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 10000000) / 0x100000000)
    jg l1
    invoke ReadFile, hFile, hmem, 1000h, addr readed, 0
    invoke MessageBox, 0, hmem, addr Time_title, MB_OKCANCEL
 
    jmp l2
 
l1:
    invoke MessageBox, 0, addr format, addr Time_title, MB_OKCANCEL
    cmp eax, IDOK
    jne l2
    invoke DeleteFile, addr [edi].lpstrFile
 
l2:
 
    assume edi: dword
    invoke CloseHandle, hFile
    invoke Mem_Free, hmem
    invoke Mem_Free, edi
 
    ret
main endp
end Begin
```

Answer (score -1):

Замените `cmp eax, ((3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 10000000) / 0x100000000)` на `cmp eax, 603`

Ассемблеры не могут сами вычислить выражение, поэтому считайте вручную

Также, вам нужно идти дальше по указателю чтобы дойти до поля структуры (читайте книгу K&R)

Comment: я еще пытался 0х100000000 записать как 100000000h, но пишет что "Константа слишком большая". А когда я ее уменьшил то Ассемблер все подсчитал, однако там было не то значение которое мне нужно(

Comment: используйте Filetimetosystemtime() и будет вам счастье